# How do I separate routes that have the same path but do different things?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The following route `Page/View/Id` would go to the `View` Method in the Page Controller. I'd also like the following route:

```
/{page-title}
```

to go to the same method.  That's so I could have URLs like the following:

```
http://www.mysite.com/This-Is-a-Page
```

How do I configure this, considering `This-Is-a-Page` might be a controller also?

Comment: This has been posted twice and is the same as:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591524/asp-net-mvc-routes

Answer (score 4):

If both your "controller" routes and "page" routes (see below) use the same `/something`, then you're going to have to implement the following rules:

At the top of your routes:

```
route. MapRoute(
    "ControllerRoute"
    "{controller}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    new { controller = GetControllerNameRegex() }
);

route.MapRoute(
    "PageRoute",
    "{pageSlug}"
    new { controller = "Page", action = "ShowPage" }
);
```

- No page can have a name that matches any controller in use.
- Or no controller can have the name that matches any page in use.

Since you can't really do the latter programmatically, but [you can do the former programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151841/asp-net-mvc-programatically-get-a-list-of-controllers/1152735#1152735), you can add a custom constraint to your controller routes, so that it will only hit if you happen to type the name of a controller:

```
private static string GetControllerNameRegex()
{
    var controllerNamesRegex = new StringBuilder();
    List<string> controllers = GetControllerNames();
    controllers.ForEach(s =>
            controllerNamesRegex.AppendFormat("{0}|", s));
    return controllerNamesRegex.ToString().TrimEnd('|');
}

private static List<Type> GetSubClasses<T>()
{
    return Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(type => 
           type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T))).ToList();
}

public List<string> GetControllerNames()
{
    List<string> controllerNames = new List<string>();
    GetSubClasses<Controller>().ForEach(type => controllerNames.Add(type.Name));
    return controllerNames;
}
```

> **NB**:  Best course would be to make sure not to have any pages named after your controller, and you could use the above code to enforce that at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to add a catch all, like so (place this after the default routes):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "{*query}",
    new { controller = "SomeController", action = "SomeAction" }
);
```

And the action signature would look like this:

```
public ActionResult(string query)
```

Comment: This only works if you define it before the default, if defined after default, it will assume title is a controller

Comment: Not if there is no controller for that title. This route catches all that does not match any of the above.