# Is there a way to get a list of views for a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Using the [code found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151841/asp-net-mvc-programatically-get-a-list-of-controllers), I have managed to get a list of controllers in my mvc site (and can do whatever I want with that list) but I need to also get a list of views for each controller. Is there a way to do this?

Edit: To clarify, I'm looking to do this at run-time in order to get the views dynamically.

Comment: Do you mean actions or views?

Comment: Views. Or, alternatively, all actions which return views. But the views are ultimately what I'm after.

Comment: If... you have sticked to the conventions, the views of a controller are located in ~/views/{controller}. System.IO has some goodies for that case

Comment: There can be an amount of shared views.

Comment: Views are not directly linked to controllers.  By default they are located using conventions but you can specify a specific view by path as well.  As Iboshuizen said, you can always enumerate the files in a directory.

Comment: I thought as much but I was hoping... Thanks for the confirmation. (put it as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Roslyn to build a tool that will analyze your syntax for
return View() statements.

but if you you use one function called ReturnViewByCondition(condition), Roslyn will consider it as a single result.

I see also the way to calculate Views file count in Controller folder, but it significantly depend on your ViewEngine implementation.

So, in most generic way, I would say "no", you can not have this statistics without siginifcant efforts in static analysis automation